# Grandfather-Grandchildren Family Photograph Combinatorics Problem.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many different ways a grandfather along with two of his grandsons and four granddaughters can be seated in a line for a photograph so that he is always in the middle and the two grandsons are never adjacent to each other. **[Answer]** 528

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, how many ways can you arrange 6 descendants? $6!$

Subtract from that how many ways can you arrange them with the boys together. $5!\times 2!$

Add back all the ways the boys are together, but in the middle two spots. $4!\times 2!$

$$6!-5!2!+4!2!=528$$

Comment: how you got $4!2!$ please explain

Comment: If he has boy1 to his left and boy2 to his right, there are $4!$ ways the girls can be seated.  And if he has boy2 to his left and boy1 to his right, there are $4!$ more ways to seat the girls. Those are acceptable arrangements because the grandfather is between the boys.

Comment: let me think about your maths

Comment: but what about "so that he is always in the middle".

Comment: We don't even worry about that.  We are just arranging the kids and then dropping the grandfather in the middle spot afterwards.  Thats why we were arranging 6 items instead of 7.

Answer (score 1):

1. how many ways can you arrange the four girls in a line, just by themselves?
2. How many ways can you arrange the two boys in a line, just by themselves?
3. How many ways can you pick two of the six positions for the grandchildren, regardless of the constraint on placing the boys?
4. How many of those layouts in #3 place the boys adjacent to each other? (remember: if the boys are immediately to the left and right of the grandfather, they're not adjacent)

Comment: there is a twist here you also have to maintain symmetry. i.e. grandfather must always be in the middle

Comment: @Dheeraj Are you sure? If you need a symmetry (and of what? genders?), the answer is different from given.

Comment: Grandfather must be in the middle that means there can only be three of his descendants on each of his sides {symmetry}.

Comment: It's not a true symmetry: the photographer still sees people left to right.  Forcing the position of the grandfather simply changes the way the grandson adjacency rule ends up working out.  In fact, if the grandfather were required to have, say, only one grandchild to his right, the problem would work out the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Defining the pair of positions where the grandsons appear, along with the order of grandsons and granddaughters uniquely specifies an arrangement. There are only $4$ pairs of positions which the grandsons can't occupy.